# Does ajaxComplete() works on trigger()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got x selects & inputs and each select & inputs change the values of the next selects & inputs (like a research tool) using Ajax. The number of select can change according to different parameters.

This code I've made doesn't seems to work :

```
$('body').find('select, input').each(function(i, e) { 
    $(e).trigger('change').ajaxComplete(function () { continue; } );
});
```

Is there any way to wait the end of each ajax call before continue to the next element ? setTimeout() isn't a good solution there because some AJAX take many time to generate (impacting a database with more a 4 millions rows).

Here is an example of an Ajax call I use for one select - please remind that in my case, each ajax call is different (page, args, success actions), but every ajax call return a JSON :

```
$.ajax({
    url:'load_product.php',
    method:'POST',
    cache:false,
    dataType:'json',
    data:{s:$(this).val()},
    success:function(a, b, c) {
        if(typeof a.error == "string") {
            showError(a.typeError, a.error);
        }

        if(typeof a.product_ean == "string") {
            $('input#product').val(a.product);
            $('input#product').trigger('change');
        }
    },
    error:function(a, b, c) {
        showError('danger', b);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, that's not how it works. There is a way to do what you require, but you'd need to listen to the XHR/promise returned from the AJAX calls. If you want more specific help, please add the AJAX logic to the question.

Comment: Hello. I just edited my post. To be honest, I have no idea how to make it, actually.